# How to open big text files in UWP Textbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to open big text files **(1MB and over)**. I can open **500KB-700KB** sized text files with my code. How can I open **1MB and over** text files.

**My file opening code:**

```cs
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker()
{
    ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
};
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

StorageFile storageFile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (storageFile != null)
{
    var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream()))
    {
        TextBox.Text = sReader.ReadToEnd();
     }
}
```

Comment: the limit you are running into, is the textbox!
Please add some error messages.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I don't get any errors. When I try to open large files, my application crashes without error.

Comment: setting a breakpoint on the last line ```.ReadToEnd()``` and do a step won't throw an exception?

Comment: I think `TextBox` is mainly designed for small to medium size texts. For large texts I would try using `RichTextBox`. But I have not really used UWP, so I might be mistaken.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I tried but now my application does not crash, waits too much and slows down the computer.

Comment: Because of bad performance in UWP textbox, here my own textbox implementation (supports textfiles with 10MB or more): https://www.nuget.org/packages/TextControlBox.JuliusKirsch

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RichTextBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock?view=winrt-22621#examples).

In my tests, it takes 3 to 4 seconds to open a 2MB text file and the window is not unresponsive, the actual effect is better than `TextBlock` and `RichEditBox`.

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" .../>
```

---

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker()
{
    ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
};
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

StorageFile storageFile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (storageFile != null)
{
    var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream()))
    {
        //get all data
        var stringText  = sReader.ReadToEnd();

        Run run = new Run();
        run.Text = stringText; 
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(run); 
    
        richTextBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
                
    }
}
```